# Why does highchart add a padding for a certain bar chart?

Tags: highcharts

I encountered a very strange highcharts behaviour.

I am rendering the same chart in two containers with only one px difference in height:

```
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height:118px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<div id="container2" style="min-width: 310px; height:117px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

The first graph renders the y-axis to 100 and adds unnecessary extra space. The second graph aligns the axis to use only as much space as necessary.

Here's a link to a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/647cg3mp/

Any idea where this extra padding comes from all of a sudden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That behavior is related with `tickInterval` and `tickPixelInterval` properties. You can change it for example by increasing `tickPixelInterval` or by setting `tickAmount` to `2`.

> **tickInterval: number**
>
> The interval of the tick marks in axis units. When undefined, the tick interval is computed to approximately follow
>   the tickPixelInterval on linear and datetime axes.

```
yAxis: {
    tickPixelInterval: 73,
    ...
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/do46qhgx/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPixelInterval

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickInterval

Answer (score 0):

I ran your fiddle. At first I didnt know what you meant by padding but will deduce you are referring to the range of the y-axis: it's different for the two divs. You can explicitly set the max of the y-axis range in your params,

```
"yAxis": {

    "min": 0,
    "max": 100,
```

which would resolve your problem, in the sense that the two charts would use the same range. As a working solution, you could query the data to determine what the max would be in for any situation, and then round to 50 increments or another suitable increment based on your needs, then use that as the max.

Comment: Sorry if you did not understand me right. It's hard to express an issue so that everyone gets what you mean. :-) Setting a max won't help. What I want is a chart that uses all of the available space to display the biggest bar (like in 'container2'). What I don't want is a fixed height where much space is wasted (like in 'container'). By the way, setting a fixed max for y is ignored in the first container.